# The adverb "today" before the verb "be" in the middle of a sentence. Correct? But there's no such a rule

Tags: sentence-construction, adverb-placement

I've come across these sentences:

"American society today is a world of conflict, challenge, struggle, and potential."

"Traffic jams today are hardcore"

They both violate the rules of placing adverbs of definite time in a sentence.
I've searched and haven't found any rule other than: You ought to put it in the front position or in the end of a sentence. Like "Today I'm going to buy ice-cream" or "I'm going to buy ice-cream today".

Is there such a rule?

Comment: Where did you find your rule about the placing of adverbs?

Comment: @RonaldSole I found that in almost any grammar book I took, i. e., in general, you should structure sentences in this order [the subject][the simple predicate][the direct object][the adverbial (manner,place,time)]

Answer (score 3):

*Today* can be placed there because in these sentences it does not attach to the verb but to the subject noun phrase.

> [Traffic jams today] are hardcore.

Other expressions of time can do the same thing:

> [The meeting last week] was productive.

A noun phrase can be qualified this way whatever its role:

> He's going to tell me about [the meeting yesterday]

In some contexts it can be ambiguous where the time expression does attach, but this is usually not a problem, eg

> He told me about the meeting yesterday.